# Convergence of decreasing decrements of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\beta_m\searrow 0$ such that $\alpha_m:=\beta_m-\beta_{m+1}\searrow 0$.

Define $b_n:=\inf\{m:\alpha_m<2^{-n}\}$. Is it true that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n}<\infty?
$$

For example, if $\beta_m=\frac 1 m$, then $b_n\sim 2^{n/2}$, so that the above series converges.

A critical case is when $\beta_m=1/\log m$, whence $\alpha_m\sim 1/m(\log m)^2$, and $b_n\sim 2^n/n^2$, so the series converges.

Edited: I am sorry I had a typo: I meant $\beta_m:=1/\log m$, not $\alpha_m:=1/\log m$. In the latter case, this is a simple question. However, it is not in the former case.

Comment: For your critical case: if I understand correctly, that means you have $b_n \geq e^{2^n}$. So $\sum_n \frac{e^{2^n}}{2^n} = \infty$.

Comment: Oh, and I don't understand your example. If $\alpha_m = 1/m$, how do you get $b_n \approx 2^{n/2}$ instead of $b_n \approx 2^{n}$?

Comment: I am sorry I had a typo. Now I modified my question so it makes more sense.

Comment: For $\beta_m = 1/\log m$, you can show that $\alpha_m \approx 1/(m\log m)$ (these $\approx$ can be made rigorous), and so $b_n \approx \frac{2^n}{n}$ and the series will diverge.

Comment: Thanks! I am interested in how you obtained $b_n\sim 2^n/n$.

Comment: If that can wait 30mn, I'll write it then.

Comment: Oh I thought $\alpha_m\sim 1/m(\log m)^2$ instead, which is critical in this case. And then $b_n\sim 2^n/n^2$, so it converges.

Comment: You are right, i had made a mistake.

Comment: @SingfookSangwood are you still interested in this question?

Comment: @mathworker21 Actually I have solved this question. I am posting the solution online once I have time.

Answer (score 1):

*For what it's worth (this is community wiki, feel free to edit) here is the analysis of your critical case.*

Consider $\beta_m = \frac{1}{\ln m}$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_m &= \beta_m - \beta_{m+1} = \frac{1}{\ln m}\left( 1- \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{m})}{\ln m}}\right)= \frac{1}{\ln m}\left( 1- \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{m\ln m} + o(\frac{1}{m\ln m})}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{m\ln^2 m}+ o\left(\frac{1}{m\ln^2 m}\right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Now, in light of the above, let's look at 
$$
\frac{1}{m\ln^2 m} \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \tag{2}
$$
for $n\geq 1$. Rearranging and rewriting the RHS, this is equivalent to
$$
2\sqrt{m}\ln\sqrt{m} \geq 2^{n/2}\,.
$$
Since $2x\ln x = 2^{n/2}$ has solution $x=\frac{2^{n/2}}{n \ln 2} + o\left(\frac{2^{n/2}}{n}\right)$ (asymptotics taken as $n\to\infty$), we get that
$$
b_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2\ln^2 2}
$$
so that by comparison with the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2\ln^2 2}$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n} < \infty\,.\tag{3}
$$

As a final remark, note that the "barrier" for that sort of $\alpha_m$ that would lead to divergence is $\alpha_m = \frac{1}{m\ln m}$. However, to get this one would need to take $\beta_m = \ln\ln m$, and this does *not* satisfy the assumption that $(\beta_m)_m$ be decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your critical case $ \alpha_{m} = \frac{1}{\lg(m)} $ is a counter-example.

Notice that $ b_{n} = 2^{(2^{n+1})} $, since we have

$$ \frac{1}{\lg(m)} < 2^{-n} \implies m > 2^{(2^{n})} $$

and $\alpha_{m}$ is monotonous.

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{(2^{n+1})}}{2^{n}} = \infty $$

Actually, it is more than critical, we could make the it diverge with much less.

Comment: I am sorry I had a typo, which made this question trivial. Now I modified my question.